# Не отображаются изображения на localhost (React)

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs

Добрый день, проблема в том, что не открываются изображения, даже если оно лежит в той же папке, что и сам компонент... На самом деле изображения лежат совсем в другой папке, но из-за того что они не хотят открываться, начал их уже в ту же папку скидывать, а всеравно не открывается. Испробовал кучу путей, форматы другие...

например задаю:

```
technologies: [
    {
      name: 'development',
      path: 'dev.png',
      link: '/'
    }
...

{
      this.state.technologies.map(function (res, i) {
        return <a key={i} href={res.link} >
          <img src={res.path} />
          <span class="name">{res.name}</span>
        </a>
      })
    }
```

Изображение лежит в этой же папке.

Comment: в консоле , отладчике есть ошибки какие-то, покажите ?

Comment: В консоли: 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
left.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
settings.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
process.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
coding.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: нужно больше информации, как вы собираете проект? и да вот, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: юзаю npm, webpack

Comment: Если задать, например, из css файла бэкграунд - то картинка отображается, если же прописать какой-то img src из компонента, то не отображается. Бред какой-то. Может в webpack конфиге что-то не то, но вроде все норм, и вообще не должно влиять

Comment: а если правой кнопкой по элементу с картинкой , там какой не правильный путь ?

Comment: в span нужно className, а путь к картинке вида ./dev.png